# Proving Convergence for Fixed Point Iteration

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

The question is: Let $f (x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{2}-x$. Find, with proof, some interval I for which the fixed point iteration method is guaranteed to converge if the initial guess $x_0$ is in I.

By Fixed Point Theorem, we need to find an interval where $|f'(x)|<1$, but the function $|f(x)|$ in the question is never less than $1$ so  what other method can be used to answer the question or does no such intereval exist?

Comment: same question as yesterday... things change if, as seems likely, the problem is to numerically solve $f(x) = 0.$  If so, the function to be iterated is something else, not $f$ itself. Do you have some source for this, perhaps a page in a book or website? Somewhere before this question, it will identify what the method is and what is is used for, with examples.

Comment: I see. You got a fairly good answer yesterday.

Comment: I know how to do fixed point iteration. The question I'm asking is how do find an interval where it is guaranteed to converge to a fixed point which requires fixed point theorem.  But, fixed point theorem will not work in this case since the absolute value of the derivative of the function is never less than 1 which is a requirement of the theorem.

Comment: Mathematica gives me
$$
\texttt{Solve[E^(-x)/2 == x, x]} = W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),
$$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1):

As people have been pointing out, to numerically find the number $x$ solving $\frac{e^{-x}}{2} - x = 0.$ First thing is to write it as something equals $x,$ which is just $\frac{e^{-x}}{2} = x .$ So, you are going to iterate
$$ g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{2} $$
And, of course, $|g'(x)| < 1$
 on a large interval

Here is a sample of iteration, beginning with $x=0$

Might be worth emphasizing that each equals signs below means "is to be replaced by"

```
? x=0
%6 = 0
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%7 = 0.5000000000000000000000000000
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%8 = 0.3032653298563167118018997675
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%9 = 0.3692015749873654911343188241
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%10 = 0.3456430252140760192530275011
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%11 = 0.3538825481550003611247199733
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%12 = 0.3509787043533093096593776714
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%13 = 0.3519993729022750369484926496
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%14 = 0.3516402815009218578123347587
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%15 = 0.3517665751765076289389374291
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%16 = 0.3517221520880169785227126740
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%17 = 0.3517377770193545907065447750
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%18 = 0.3517322811836759583191602793
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%19 = 0.3517342142518081218640400935
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%20 = 0.3517335343262647315210185872
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%21 = 0.3517337734789604899165309460
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%22 = 0.3517336893608904316822977634
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%23 = 0.3517337189480507995902729222
? x = exp( -x) / 2
%24 = 0.3517337085412490042274794707
?
```